# What did the Yuuzhan Vong use for illumination?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yuuzhan-vong

Wookieepedia offers no explanation of this. Does anyone know what the light biots used by the Yuuzhan Vong were called? It's been a while since I read the books and don't want to dig through 20 books to find the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lambents](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lambent), the crystalline fruit of a plant that they grew on various planets. The level of light they gave off could be controlled telepathically and Anakin Solo was even able to use one as a lightsaber crystal (in *The New Jedi Order: Edge of Victory I: Conquest*).

[image: A Yuuzhan Vong examining a lambent, from Star Wars: Legacy #12, found on Wookieepedia]

According to Wookieepedia, they also made some use of [bioluminescent lichen](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Glow-lichen) for lighting ships and other areas but they don't seem to have been as plot-relevant as the lambents.